# Indefinite geodesics and infinte path

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry

I read the theorem 1.4.7. in "Riemannian Geometry and Geometric Analysis" (2005) that states:

$\textbf{Theorem 1.4.7.}$ Let $M$ be a compact Riemannian manifold. Then for any $p \in M$, the exponential map $\exp_p$ is defined on all of $T_pM$, and any geodesic may be extended indefinitely in each direction.

$\textbf{My question:}$ Let the sphere $\mathbb{S}^2$ to be the compact Riemannian manifold, then can we deduce the fact from the theorem that: you have a geodesic as the trajectory for a particle on the surface of the sphere, if the sphere is expanded indefinitely, the particle will still reach point B due to that $\exp_p$ is defined on all $T_p\mathbb{S}^2$.

Comment: what is "point B" and what does "the sphere is expanded indefinitely" mean?

Comment: Sorry: Let say you have a path from A to B (call it $\gamma$) such that the path is the geodesic on the sphere. If we add the confition that we can expand/stretch the radius of the sphere to $\infty$, then for a "particle" travelling on $\gamma$ the endpoint B is still reachable.

Comment: The "limit sphere with infinite radius" is not well defined as stated so I'm not sure about the question

Comment: I will try with a better clarification: Given a beach ball with radius $R=1$. Later we draw a path on the ball with endpoints $A$ to $B$ (call it $\gamma_{AB}$). Now, if we keep blowing up the beach ball indefinitely, i.e. that the $R$ is getting larger and larger to infinity. Then for someone taking that path on the ball, will $\gamma_{AB}$ be reachable? Assuming loosely that $\gamma_{AB}$ "may be extended indefinitely" even though that the radius continuously getting larger.

Comment: For each fixed $r \in (0,+\infty)$ the sphere endowed with the round metric of radius $r$ is well-defined and is a compact Riemannian manifold: by the statement you provided, it is geodesically complete. Nevertheless, there is no limit of this sphere as $r\to \infty$: how do you even define that path $\gamma_{AB}$ in this limiting case? Moreover, the map $\exp_p$ highly depends on the metric on $S^n$. If you change the metric, you change the exponential map. If there is no metric, there is no exponential map.

Comment: Theorem 1.4.7 applies only to one compact Riemannian manifold at a time. So the short answer to your question is: No, you cannot deduce the fact you want from that theorem. I suspect that is not exactly what you meant to ask, but in that case it is rather unclear *what* you intended to ask.